# Bootstrap 3 grid resizing issue

Tags: html, css, grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

So basically I am building a full screen food image grid using bootstrap 3. I have used container-fluid and the appropriate columns to define the width of my rows and breakpoints. Each of the columns contains a food image and uses the class - col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4

I didn't want a gutter between the images so I removed the left and right padding assigned to the column class which gives me the exact look I want. Now when I resize the grid, it all works fine. However in between screen widths 950px and 980px, the images have a gutter between them vertically. I am unsure whats causing this. Does anyone have an idea?

I have attached a few pictures to illustrate

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLPp.jpg

Thanks

EDIT: http://www.bootply.com/xXaaLRWKTL - Bootply. The gutter comes back in the following example around 991px width

Comment: Post your code and make a fiddle of it

Comment: Here you go. http://www.bootply.com/xXaaLRWKTL . It breaks in the example starting around width 991px

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the gutters aren't actually back. The image is reaching its max width/height, and so is no longer scaling up. This max w/h happens before Bootstrap switches to the next break, and so there are gaps between the images.

If you use an image with a larger max width and height, you should not have a gap.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using media query to adjust the spaces between you picture.

```
@media (max-width: 978px ){
    div {
        padding-left: 0px ; 
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
}
```

Hope that works for you